# Asymptotic complexity of a simple pseudocode function

Tags: complexity-theory

I want to understand how the asymptotic running times of this function can be deduced.

Input: Array A containing n integers A[1] to A[n]
Output: Two-dimensional n-by-n array B in which B[i,j] for i<j contains:

$ \sum_{k=i}^j A[k] = A[i] + A[i+1] + ... A[j] $

I've attempted to work out the running times for each line of pseudocode

```
for i=1 to n                                     O(n)
    for j=i to n                                 O(n^2)
        add up array entries A[i] through A[j]   O(n^3) ??
        store result in b[i,j]                   O(n^2)
return B
```

So total running time is $ O(n^3) $
I also need to work out the complexity in terms of big-$ \omega $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of matters how you implement `add up array entries A[i] through A[j]`:

```
for i = 1 to n
    for j = i to n
        sum = 0
        for k = i to j
            sum = sum + A[i]
        b[i,j] = sum
return b
```

The above is O(n^3) and Omega(n^3) thus Theta(n^3). However, if you calculate `sum` differently:

```
for i = 1 to n
    sum = 0
    for j = i to n
        sum = sum + A[i]
        b[i,j] = sum
return b
```

This is O(n^2), Omega(n^2) and Theta(n^2). To your specific question - O and Omega will normally be the same (that is, you will normally get Theta bounds) if you are doing runtime analysis as in your question based on straightforward code. Theta bounds are the rule when looking at specific implementations, not the exception.